# How to interpret Go stacktrace

Tags: go

I am getting this stacktrace when running a go program:

```
        /home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.6.linux.amd64/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3e6
github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/statsd.(*Client).Event(0x0, 0xc8200c7ec8, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/statsd/statsd.go:286 +0x11f
github.com/some/path/server.(*Server).buildAndUpdate(0xc820024068, 0xc820064600, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/some/path/server/http.go:86 +0xf9f
created by github.com/some/path/server.(*Server).processPullRequestEvent
        /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/some/path/server/http.go:169 +0x53f
```

The signature of the Event function is:

```
func (c *Client) Event(e *Event) error
```

which can also be seen here: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/blob/cc2f4770f4d61871e19bfee967bc767fe730b0d9/statsd/statsd.go#L285

The type definition for `Event` can be seen here: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/blob/cc2f4770f4d61871e19bfee967bc767fe730b0d9/statsd/statsd.go#L333

The type definition for `Client` can be seen here: https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/blob/cc2f4770f4d61871e19bfee967bc767fe730b0d9/statsd/statsd.go#L59

My question is, how do I interpret the memory addresses on this line, and more generally, any stack traces which involve typed variables as targets and as arguments?

```
github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/statsd.(*Client).Event(0x0, 0xc8200c7ec8, 0x0, 0x0)
```

When I looked at http://www.goinggo.net/2015/01/stack-traces-in-go.html (which is the only information I was able to find on the subject), I didn't see anything about how to interpret the output when structs were involved.

Comment: It might be worth bugging Datadog support about it, if you're a customer of theirs.

Comment: @twotwotwo appreciate the pointer, however I'm not bothered by the fact that my program isn't working. What I really want to know is how to interpret the stack trace.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Thanks to a comment from @twotwotwo, I think I figured this out.

In this line

```
github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/statsd.(*Client).Event(0x0, 0xc8200c7ec8, 0x0, 0x0)
```

- the first `0x0` is the `*Client`, which is indeed nil.
- `0xc8200c7ec8` is `*Event`
- the following `0x0, 0x0` represent the return value of type `error`. `error`, according to http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go, is an interface. According to http://research.swtch.com/interfaces, interfaces are stored as two pointers. The first pointer points to the type information stored in the interface, and the second pointer points to the data stored in the interface.

I wrote the following program to demonstrate to myself how different function signatures appear in a stack trace:

```
package main

import "errors"

type X struct {
        i int
}

type Y struct {
}

func (y *Y) foo(x *X) {
        panic("panic in foo")
}

func (y *Y) bar(x *X) (*Y) {
        panic("panic in bar")
        return y
}

func (y *Y) baz(x *X) (error) {
        panic("panic in baz")
        return errors.New("error in baz")
}

func (y *Y) bam() {
        panic("panic in bam")
}

func main() {
        y := new(Y)
        x := new(X)
        // comment out the ones you don't want to check
        y.foo(x)
        y.bar(x)
        y.baz(x)
        y.bam()
}
```

When `bam` is called, which acts on `*Y` but has no arguments or return value, the output contains:

```
main.(*Y).bam(0xc82002df48)
```

When `foo` is called, which acts on `*Y` and takes a `*X` as argument, but has no return value, the output contains:

```
main.(*Y).foo(0xc820033f30, 0xc820033f30)
```

When `bar` is called, which acts on `*Y`, takes a `*X` as argument, and returns a `*Y`, the output contains:

```
main.(*Y).bar(0xc820033f30, 0xc820033f30, 0x40fb46)
```

When `baz` is called, which acts on `*Y`, takes `*X` as argument, and returns an `error` (which is an interface), the output contains:

```
main.(*Y).baz(0xc820033f38, 0xc820033f38, 0x0, 0x0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step examples!

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a nil pointer dereference. (Unless you are using package `unsafe`, which you probably shouldn't touch, so I'm assuming you're not.)

It looks like the `e` argument to `func (c *Client) Event(e *Event) error` is `nil` when called from `github.com/some/path/server/http.go:86`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I'm not interested in solving this particular problem as much as I am interested in learning how to interpret what the various addresses in github.com/DataDog/datadog-go/statsd.(*Client).Event(0x0, 0xc8200c7ec8, 0x0, 0x0) mean. I will edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: @des4maisons -- the receiver (the `*Client`) comes first in the argument list. `0x0` is a nil pointer. `0xc8200c7ec8` is the raw value of the Event pointer. Not sure about the last two; they may be the two words in the _returned_ [interface value](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces). Note that you're getting a dump of the raw words passed, so, e.g. [a slice would show up as three words](http://research.swtch.com/godata). There's something called [panicparse](https://github.com/maruel/panicparse) that makes these more digestible and you may even find skimming its source useful.

Comment: @twotwotwo thanks, that's exactly what it was. I wrote up an answer expanding on your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly: method receiver(if any), explicit arguments(if any), return values(if any).

To understand the stack traces, you need to first understand Go's data structures' internal representation. For example, arguments of slice type have three components thus three values in the stack trace of the func: data(a pointer), len(an int), cap(an int).

You might find [this article](https://dev.to/mcaci/reading-stack-traces-in-go-3ah5) useful.